# angularj js : html template insertion: modify the attribute value with each insertion

Tags: html, angularjs, templates, insert, attributes

Hello stack overflow community!
this is a mini version of my code. in [this example](https://plnkr.co/edit/ASYPOoYDduiOlz4YHmSG?p=preview) I'm trying to insert my template in each div in the index.html and change its id with each insertion.
+ why do the h1 elements disappear?

```
    <div id= "simpleSearchType OR advancedSearchType OR expertSearchType"  >
    this is the div to be inserted
</div >
```

any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way of doing this would be to use the `ng-if` directive.

You can set the `searchType` variable in the controller and switch the view appropriately on the template by hooking the divs to `ng-if`.